# On the nature of the soul - ability to create, fade, disappear, or still

Tags: philosophy, advaita, yoga, sankhya, shad-darshana

### Nature of the soul: Perishable, Uniqueness, etc.

In Indian philosophy, there are multiple schools of philosophy including - Advaita, ShuddhaAdvaita (Vedantic), Sankhya, Yoga, Madhyamaka, Jaina, etc.

On the very nature of soul, various Indian schools have their very own thought:

| School | Nature | Perishable | Is Unique? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Advaita | **Atman = Brahman**. Eternal, infinite, permanent, most powerful, etc. | No | No |
| Davita | **Atman is separate from Brahman**. Brahman is the creator and Atman is just a tiny creation. Atman has three Gunas. It is NOT infinite but rather created from a creator who is beyond the three gunas. | No | Yes |
| ShuddhaAdvaita | **Atman = Brahman, as well as Atman is a part of Brahman**. Fire-spark example. [*Similar properties as in Advaita*] | No | No |
| Shankhya | **Purusha and Prakriti are different.** There's no *ishvara* to enforce the laws of karma or *Brahman*, but liberation is Purusha knowing its own nature. Each Purusha is unique and, after liberation is the equivalent as others. | No | Yes |
| Yoga | **Seedless Samadhi (Nirbeeja samadhi) is the goal where the waves of Vrittis stop.** Each purusha has unique chitta and vrittis, when such vrittis stop and the samadhi is such that cannot be reproduced with any beeja, it is said to be in the highest state of samadhi - Nirbeeja Samadhi (before Kaivalya Samadhi). | Yes* | Yes |
| Madhyamaka | **The Essence of everything in physicality is connected and a goal beyond physicality, where nothing is connected (total independence) called Shunya is meditated.** Belief in a permanent/unchanging soul may or may not be required. | Yes | Yes/No |

[*Although I'm not sure about this. But the usual wave and pond analogy suggests that Vrittis (that come from atman) are waves in the pond that should settle themselves after sometime, or decay after a long time and nirbeeja can be attained by that too.*]

**Note:** Please correct me if I'm anywhere wrong here.

### Non-unique Soul?

Although it is an assumption made in Hinduism (especially those following Brahma Sutras) that the soul must be infinite (never dying or decaying) and unique before attaining Moksha. But I find very less texts that discuss or defend against the very intrinsic properties of the soul like:

- If they decay with time?
- If they split into *children soul*, each having own subjective experience. (This could have consequences like the *jagat satya*.
- Existence of it after liberation? (Do they dissolve? (Advaita) vs stay there without any action? (Yoga) vs disappear? (*Madhyamaka* if soul is considered))

Are there any quotes from principal Upanishads (or equivalent darshan-sutras) that limit that the soul cannot create sub-souls (atman cannot have his own creations), or decay/fade with time or on the nature of liberation, what happens after jivanmukta dies?

Comment: As Far As I have read Shuddhadvaita, A least the one of Vallabha doesn't believe in Atman=Brahman in the same sense as Advaita does

Comment: @Invictus I'm not sure about it. I haven't read their commentary, but here's a reference: https://byjus.com/free-ias-prep/philosophy-in-medieval-india/#:~:text=He%20said%20that%20Krishna%20was%20Brahman%20and%20that%20the%20soul%20and%20God%20are%20one%20and%20the%20same.

Comment: @User29449 the table you make, can you add vaisheshik darshan also?

Comment: @User29449 Not a reliable reference. The vallabhas hold the relation between Brahman and atman as equivalent to that of Fire and it's sparks.

Comment: Honestly, the source you are using is pretty inauthentic and unreliable. It's like wiki, not trustable content. Pātañjala Yoga aligns with Sāṅkhya, and there are multiple Puruṣas in Sāṅkhya. Also, Puruṣa is not perishable in Sāṅkhya-Yoga. In Mādhyamaka, an ātman or Brahman is not accepted. The description of Mādhyamaka is pretty loose and incorrect.

Comment: Ātman is by definition and its nature imperishable and eternal. It's not prone to decay or fade, even upon attaining mokṣa. All Vaidika darśanas concur on this. It's not an assumption, that's how ātman is, and this is known by both nāstika and āstika darśanas. Bauddhas and Cārvākas reject an ātman thatswhy. In Bhāgavata Purāṇa (7.7.19-20), Prahlāda mentions the 12 lakṣaṇas of ātman, these are - nitya, avyaya, śuddha, eka, kṣetrajña, āśraya, avikriya, svadṛk, hetu, vyāpaka, asaṅgī, and anāvṛta.

Comment: @Hope I'm not sure, but from what I know from the summary, that is pretty similar to the approach as in Nyaya school, except there are small building blocks that are called *anu*. There's a cosmic force that is responsible for anu. In that case, it becomes similar to Shankhya (Tho, I'm not totally sure).

Comment: @Invictus Thank you for the example. Yes, that's true. ShuddhaAdvaita accepts atman as brahman as well as also VasisthaAdvaita view is that one is a tiny part of a bigger brahman. Both via fire-spark example, as spark isn't something very different from fire, but a part of fire too. I've edited the qustion to address that.

Comment: @Bingming For Yoga part - Yoga uses the terminology - *chitta* and *vritti* for each purusha more than, *purusha-prikriti* terms of Shankhya. This is a minor difference. *Chitta* are like the shape of a pot and *vrittis* are waves of water in that pot. The goal of Yoga is samadhi - to silence vrittis. Waves of water itself get still after sometime - suggesting a samadhi and once after nirbeeja samadhi, it doesn't takes birth again. This suggests that if vrittis are left itself, the soul ( caused by the disturbance of vrittis) fades itself with time.

Comment: @Bingming The premise of Madhyamaka was a conversation between Buddha and Vikkhu where Buddha concludes that - there is atman, there is no atman, there is atman as well as no atman, there is no atman as well as no atman. This led to the formulation of Madhyamaka by Nagajurna which was an attack on the Nyaya school of philosophy. The conclusion is that Buddhist belief is not affected by the existence or not existence of Atman altogether.

Comment: @Bingming According to Dalai Lama, the essence of Buddhism isn't about Nihilism, but the essence of everything that is interconnected events (dhammas). Zhiyi's thoughts shadow the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_philosophy#:~:text=In%20Tiantai%20thought%2C%20ultimate%20reality%20is%20simply%20the%20very%20phenomenal%20world%20of%20interconnected%20events%20or%20dharmas.

Comment: I never said Buddhism is nihilistic, but you seem to assumed I said so, out of nowhere, which is very strange. If you want I can show you ślokas from Mādhyamika śāstras, which argue against the existence of ātman. You can look Mūlamadhyakārikā, its commentaries by Candrakīrti, Bhāviveka, etc., Bhāviveka's Mādhyamakahṛdaya, Āryādeva's Catuḥśataka, etc. They are strongly against existence of an ātman. I don't go on wikipedia btw.
Pratītyasamutpāda itself negates the existence of any independent and permanent entity like ātman. As for tathāgatagarbha, that's not ātman.

Comment: Rejecting ātman doesn't imply nihilism, so actually you didn't understand the Bauddha siddhānta and Buddhavacana in the first place. Even Buddha himself showed that any idea of an ātman is reducible to the pañcaskandhas. And there's no permanent and independent entity like ātman. He wasn't a nihilistic, but he didn't preach the idea of an ātman. In fact, the samyak-dṛṣṭi (part of the āryāṣṭāṅga mārga) includes non-acceptance of the idea of an independent & eternal entity like ātman. It would be better to clear some basics first.

Comment: Also, vṛttis are not the ātman in Yoga and they don't affect the ātman really, you have a perspective which doesn't at all align with Yogasūtras and its commentaries. Puruṣa is not the result of vṛttis. Please get your basics clear of the siddhāntas, because you are messing everything up, due to ignorance. Anyway, I have discussed enough, and don't see any point in continuing this discussion. I would suggest you to study actual śāstras, not wiki, byju, etc., you won't understand the siddhāntas from those sources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151762/discussion-between-bingming-and-user-29449).